# How to store data from MongoDB accessed by REST API in SQL-Server database as Table

Tags: sql-server, mongodb, ssis

I am newbie and needs guidance or resources to read. I have two databases, one is in Azure SQL-Server 2012 and the other is in MongoDB at remote location. I access the Azure SQL-Server data using Sql Server Management Studio (SSMS) from my PC and the data of Mongodb in browser using REST API. The retrieved data is in JSON format.

For analysis I want to merge the data from Mongodb in to SQL-Server. I don't know how to store the results of the REST API query as a table in SQL-Server 2012? Note that the columns I want to retrieve from MongoDB are not sub-structured so can easily fit in Relational database.

Comment: What is the question here? I have read this multiple times and still not really sure what you need help with.

Comment: How to put the json data in to sql server as table..

Comment: With an insert statement.

Comment: any example or link?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn921897.aspx

Comment: I wonder if it will also work in SQL-Server 2014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure SQL Database supports OPENJSON function that can parse JSON tet and transform it into a table see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/public-preview-json-in-azure-sql-database/

Comment: I used python to parse the json into csv file and then used ssis to import it as table in my existing database. I dont know how it will manage sub structures in mongodb file.